# Command Not Found when running 'svn'

Tags: command-line, package-management, svn

I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 from a usb drive. I am having issue with my wifi connection. I tried to update the network adapter but ran into this problem with the svn command.

```
sudo svn checkout http://svn.madwifi-project.org/madwifi/trunk/ madwifi-ng
```

I was using the codes from [Madwifi installation for Atheros card in Karmic koala](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1309072)
 however, I am stuck on step 7. It says the `sudo svn` command cannot be found when I entered in the step 7 code. I tried to find similar issue in the thread but could not find it.The thread I was reading from is closed.  I have a Atheros  Wireless Network Adapter and was trying to update it so I can use my wifi. Right now I am using a Ethernet.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
adamsfj@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
adamsfj@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers- 'uname -r'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
adamsfj@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~$ sudo apt-get install subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
adamsfj@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~$ sudo -i
root@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~# sudo svn checkout http://svn.madwifi-project.org/madwifi/trunk/madwifi-ng
sudo: svn: command not found
root@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~# sudo svn checkout http://svn.madwifi-project.org/madwifi/trunk/ madwifi -ng
sudo: svn: command not found
root@adamsfj-Aspire-4330:~#
```

Comment: What's the exact error output you get?  Paste the entire output into your question as an edit.

Comment: There's no need to run `svn` commands as `sudo`.

Answer (score 10):

Install the [`subversion` [image: Install subversion]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/subversion) package. Then try again. The `svn` binary, the Subverion client, is in that package.

By the way, the "Command not found" error also hints on this package:

```
$ svn checkout ....
The program 'svn' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Also, there's no need to run `svn` commands with elevated privileges like `sudo`. I understand you're just following a how-to there, but just don't do that.

Having said all that, zooming out on your initial issue about Wireless, I don't think this will work. Karmic Koala (9.10) is *really* old and Atheros wireless drivers aren't in the madwifi driver anymore nowadays. If I recall correctly, this is now merged in the `mac80211` driver. **Please ask a more specific question about your Wireless issue.**

Comment: I am trying to get the wifi working again. When I installed the updated version of ubutu, my wifi cannot connect. I don't know what else more I can add to this question.

Comment: @user171602 Ask a NEW question, rather than changing the topic from "Command not found" to "Wireless issue". Thanks.